# Why ajax calls doesn't load the layout in CakePHP 2.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I am wondering why if i use jquery `$.load` function or some pluging such as [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) to load content dynamically on the site, the layoug is not loaded but only the view as if it were an element.

My `$.load()` calls a controller action as if it was a normal link, like:

```
$('#demo').load("http://"+ document.domain +"/tables/users/edit/", {input : data}, function(dat){
     //whatever
});
```

This is not something I personally dislike, like this I avoid creating elements and calling them using `$this->render('/Elements/xxxx', false);` from my controllers.

I want to know if this is the proper way to work with or if it is some kind of cheat or bug of cakephp.

How should we treat this type of content which is not a proper "view" (as won't have a layout, headers...etc), but an "element" loaded dynamically? As a view? As an element?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check /Layouts/ajax.ctp this is the layout that is rendered for ajax calls. Usually you don't want to have all the header and footer around the element you request when doing an ajax call.

Comment: I am not specifying the `ajax` layout anywhere. Does it detect the ajax call automatically ?

Comment: If you are you are using the RequestHandler component, CakePHP will switch layouts automatically when it detects and Ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Burzum is on the right track.

Your controller will load the default layout unless you tell it to use /Layouts/ajax.ctp. So in your edit function you'd want to switch layouts depending on how the function is being called. For example:

```
if($this->request->is('ajax')){
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
}// else use controller default...or specify another layout to use here.
```

Comment: Well, I don't need to specify the layout as i said because I am using `RequestHandler` component.